# Finding index of smallest element in list only for elements at a certain index

Tags: python

Say I have the following lists:

```
possible_moves = [0, 1, 2, 3]
q_array = [4, 2, 3, 7, -10]
```

I'd like to get the index of the smallest element in `q_array` only for the elements at indices in `possible_moves`. Thus the output for the two lists should be 1.

I achieved it using the following code, but it really is not very Pythonic.

```
best_value = q_array[random.choice(possible_moves)]
for move in possible_moves:
    if q_array[move] <= best_value:
        best_value = q_array[move]
        move_chosen = move
return move_chosen
```

EDIT: The value returned should be the index of the smallest value, not the value itself. In the example above, 1 is returned because it is the index of the smallest value within the elements with index in `possible_moves`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data in a dict, then get the key with the minimum value.

```
>>> d = {i: q_array[i] for i in possible_moves}
>>> move_chosen = min(d, key=d.get)
1
```

This is similar to [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835835/4518341).

Answer (score 2):

Build a list comprehension containing only the desired elements, then find the `min()` of that list:

```
min([q_array[x] for x in possible_moves])
```

Comment: Thanks! The value returned should be the index of that smallest element though, not the value.

Comment: It is the value --> `q_array[x]`. I actually had this same answer verbatim but I was beat by seconds ;P

Comment: @Johny Your question said _I'd like to get the smallest element_, not _index of the smallest element_.

Comment: @JohnGordon Edited!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `min` function on the `possible_moves` list with the `__getitem__` method of the `q_array` list as the key function:

```
min(possible_moves, key=q_array.__getitem__)
```

This returns: `1`